# Non-type variable constraint

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to use the Parsec library to parse a list of `Token` values. I'd like to use the `token` function in [Text.Parsec.Prim](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html) to match a single value. It seems like this should work:

```hs
type TokenParser a = Parsec [Token] () a

mytoken :: (Token -> Bool) -> TokenParser Token
mytoken test = token showTok posFromTok testTok
  where -- and so on
```

This gives a compile error:

```
No instance for (Stream [Token] Identity Token)
  arising from a use of `Prim.token'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Stream [Token] Identity Token)
```

Okay, let's change the type declaration on `mytoken:`

```hs
mytoken :: Stream [Token] Identity Token => (Token -> Bool) -> TokenParser Token
```

This works, after we add the `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` extension.

What is going on? First of all, the `Stream` class definition in [Text.Parsec.Prim](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html) has `Monad m => Stream [tok] m tok` as one of the instances. Shouldn't `Stream [Token] Identity Token` already be covered by that instance? Second, how is it that this is even constraining anything? There are no type variables to be constrained in the type of `mytoken`.

Worse yet, when I go to use my new, "constrained" `mytoken` in another function, I get exactly the same error, `No instance for (Stream [Token] Identity Token) arising from...` It actually necessitates putting the same, seemingly no-op type constraint on the type of the function trying to call `mytoken`.

If anyone can help explain to me what this type constraint is doing, I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following file is the minimal one I could construct that reproduces your problem. (In the future, you should create such a file yourself for us.)

```
import Text.Parsec.Prim

data Token

type TokenParser a = Parsec [Token] () a

mytoken :: (Token -> Bool) -> TokenParser Token
mytoken test = token showTok posFromTok testTok

showTok = undefined
posFromTok = undefined
testTok = undefined
```

Changing the import from `Text.Parsec.Prim` to `Text.Parsec` fixes the error. (The appropriate instance is defined in `Text.Parsec.String`, which is imported by `Text.Parsec.Prim`.) You also ask why this change makes it compile but not work:

```
mytoken :: Stream [Token] Identity Token => (Token -> Bool) -> TokenParser Token
```

The general rule is that the type "C => T" says: "you can use this thing as if it were a T, provided you can show that constraint C is satisfied". So giving `mytoken` the type you did says to wait until `mytoken` is used as if it were a plain old `(Token -> Bool) -> TokenParser Token`, and as soon as it is, try to discharge the obligation of showing that `Stream [Token] Identity Token` holds. Since you still haven't imported the appropriate instance, it can't discharge that obligation and complains.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. In the future I'll be sure to include a minimally reproducing file.

Do you have any insight into what the type constraint is doing, in the case where you fail to import the appropriate instance?

Comment: @Cardano Yes, sure. I'll add a sentence about this.

Comment: Note that this instance has been [deorphanized](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/commit/ec7d75098740d9315736f2464f09b699bf37f436) recently, so this shouldn't be a problem starting from the next release.